# Is it possible to resume a generator function after python program exit and the program restarts?

Tags: python-3.x

I am wondering if there exist a possibility where a generator function/iterator function in python can pause after keyboard interrupt and whenever the program restart the generator function resume from where it is left off? Please be clear and simple when explaining this solution.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit reading on generators and the 'yield'.i've realized that generators only output a value, discard it and output another value and so forth...
The was trying to find a way to resume output for the following function after python quits

```
counter=0
def product(*args, repeat=1):
    global counter
    pools = [tuple(pool) for pool in args] * repeat
    #yield pools
    result = [[]]
    for pool in pools:
        result = [x+[y] for x in result for y in pool]
    for prod in result:
        counter=counter+1
        if counter>11:
            yield tuple(prod)

def product_function():
    for i in product('abc',repeat=3):
        print(i)
        print(counter)

product_function()
```

I finally decided to put in the a little variable called counter and once the counter is greater that the 11th word then all over values (words) are yielded and printed. I suppose i could write some codes to store the counter variable in a separate file whenever the program quits and whenever the program restarts it pulls the last counter variable from the file so that output resumes. hope this works..